# How do I simulate a UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad in ipad?

Tags: ipad

The UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad [is not supported on the iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597619/uikeyboardtypenumberpad-on-ipad). Instead, it gives the full keyboard. Is there any way around this?

Alternatively, what would be the code to make sure that the user input actually is in an integer?

Comment: no see: [uikeyboardtypenumber on ipad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597619/uikeyboardtypenumberpad-on-ipad)

Comment: What I mean by a way around this is whether anybody knows if there are any custom classes that anyone created that simulates the numberpad and that code is online.

Comment: I don't think this is a[n exact] duplicate. This question is for asking for an alternative -- even if a custom solution.