# Can I get the iPhone number pad in an iPad app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, numpad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597619/uikeyboardtypenumberpad-on-ipad)

I want to give users the option of only inputting numbers. The number pad for iPad pops up with other symbols etc. Is it possible to get the iPhone version of the number pad in an iPad app?

Comment: ok thanks I just wanted to know if there was a way to get it without creating a keyboard that is really already created

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. You can only use the UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad to get the numbers on an iPad, and the letters and symbols are not locked out. If you really need this, I would recommend looking up tutorials about making custom keyboards and using NSMutableStrings. This way, you can create your own keyboard and experience, and still have the same number pad as the iPhone.

Comment: ok thanks for the feedback. In that case I think I'm just going to go with a pickerView instead.