# How do I retrieve keystrokes from a custom keyboard on an iOS app?

Tags: ios, keyboard, inputview

I need to build a custom keyboard for my iPhone app. [Previous questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643167/iphone-objc-how-to-create-a-custom-keyboard) on the topic have focused on the visual elements of a custom keyboard, but I'm trying to understand how to retrieve the keystrokes from this keyboard.

Apple provides the inputView mechanism which makes it easy to associate a custom keyboard with an UITextField or UITextView, but they do not provide the functions to send generated keystrokes back to the associated object. Based on the typical delegation for these objects, we'd expect three functions : one of normal characters, one for backspace and one for enter. Yet, no one seems to clearly define these functions or how to use them.

How do I build a custom keyboard for my iOS app and retrieve keystrokes from it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's my custom keyboard which I believe addresses these as completely as Apple will allow:

```
//  PVKeyboard.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface PVKeyboard : UIView
@property (nonatomic,assign) UITextField *textField;
@end

//  PVKeyboard.m

#import "PVKeyboard.h"

@interface PVKeyboard () {
    UITextField *_textField;
}
@property (nonatomic,assign) id<UITextInput> delegate;
@end

@implementation PVKeyboard

- (id<UITextInput>) delegate {
    return _textField;
}

- (UITextField *)textField {
    return _textField;
}

- (void)setTextField:(UITextField *)tf {
    _textField = tf;
    _textField.inputView = self;
}

- (IBAction)dataPress:(UIButton *)btn {
    [self.delegate insertText:btn.titleLabel.text];
}

- (IBAction)backPress {
    if ([self.delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInput)]) {
        [self.delegate deleteBackward];
    } else {
        int nLen = [_textField.text length];
        if (nLen)
            _textField.text = [_textField.text substringToIndex:nLen-1];
    }
}

- (IBAction)enterPress {
    [_textField.delegate textFieldShouldReturn:_textField];
}

- (UIView *)loadWithNIB {
   NSArray *aNib = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([self class]) owner:self options:nil];
   UIView *view = [aNib objectAtIndex:0];
   [self addSubview:view];
   return view;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
   self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
   if (self)
        [self loadWithNIB];
   return self;
}
@end
```

In XCode 4.3 and later, you need to create an objective-Class (for the .h & .m files) based on UIView and a User Interface View file (for the .xib file). Make sure all three files have the same name. Using the Identity Inspector, make sure to set the XIB's File's Owner Custom Class to match the new object's name. Using the Attributes Inspector, set the form's size to Freeform and set the Status Bar to none. Using the Size Inspector, set the form's size, which should match the width of the standard keyboard (320 for iPhone portrait and 480 for iPhone landscape), but you can choose any height you like.

The form is ready to be used. Add buttons and connect them to the dataPress, backPress and enterPress as appropriate. The initWithFrame: and loadWithNIB functions will do all the magic to allow you to use a keyboard designed in Interface Builder.

To use this keyboard with a UITextField myTextField, just add the following code to your viewDidLoad:

```
self.keyboard = [[PVKeyboard alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,488,320,60)];
self.keyboard.textField = self.myTextField;
```

Because of some limitations, this keyboard isn't reusable, so you'll need one per field. I can almost make it reusable, but I'm just not feeling that clever. The keyboard is also limited to UITextFields, but that's mainly because of limitations in implementing the enter key functionality, which I'll explain below.

Here's the magic that should allow you to design a better keyboard than this starter framework...

I've implemented the only property of this keyboard, textField, using a discreet a discrete setter (setTextField) because:

1. we need the UITextField object to handle the enter problem
2. we need UITextField because it conforms to the UITextInput protocol which conforms to UIKeyInput, which does much of our heavy lifting
3. it was a convenient place to set the UITextInput's inputView field to use this keyboard.

You'll notice a second private property named delegate, which essentially typecasts the UITextField pointer to a UITextInput pointer. I probably could have done this cast inline, but I sensed this might be useful as a function for future expansion, perhaps to include support for UITextView.

The function dataPress is what inserts text input the edited field using the insertText method of UIKeyInput. This seems to work in all versions back to iOS 4. For my keyboard, I'm simply using the label of each button, which is pretty normal. Use whatever NSStrings strike your fancy.

The function dataBack does the backspace and is a little more complicated. When the UIKeyInput deleteBackward works, it works wonderfully. And while the documentation says it works back to iOS 3.2, it seems to only work back to iOS 5.0, which is when UITextField (and UITextView) conformed to the UITextInput protocol. So prior to that, you're on your own. Since iOS 4 support is a concern to many, I've implemented a lame backspace which works on the UITextField directly. If not for this requirement, I could have made this keyboard work with UITextView. And this backspace isn't as general, only deleting the last character, while deleteBackward will work properly even if the user moves the cursor.

The function enterPress implements the enter key, but is a complete kludge because Apple doesn't seem to give a method for invoking the enter key. So enterPress simply calls the UITextField's delegate function textFieldShouldReturn:, which most programmers implement. Please note that the delegate here is the UITextFieldDelegate for the UITextField and NOT the delegate property for the keyboard itself.

This solution goes around the normal keyboard processing, which hardly matters in the case of UITextField, but makes this technique unusable with UITextView since there is now way to insert line breaks in the text being edited.

That's pretty much it. It took 24 hours of reading and cobbling to make this work. I hope it helps somebody.

Comment: While I'm answering your comment, I have one for you. :)  Your `enterPress` method has one minor flaw. It assumes the `UITextFieldDelegate` implements the `textFieldShouldReturn:` method. This may not be a safe assumption.

Comment: You answer your own question?

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, I've made that assumption (I say as much in the text, because we're all pretty much required to resign as First Responder and perhaps pick the next field to become First Responder). But you're right, it would be safer/better to check to make sure the method exists before calling.

Comment: @sunkehappy I know... I didn't originally post it this way. But when I posted a single post with a general answer to a question I'd seen posted a number of times both here and in the Apple Developer forums, I was asked specifically to ask it as a question and then answer it. It seems odd to me, too, but when in Rome...

Comment: Yes, Greg, this helped me a lot, thank you very much for taking the time to share it!

Comment: In better world the keyboard should not know (retain, copy, store information) about the input view. IMHO. I'd prefer rmaddy's answer.

Comment: Take a look at my example, which addresses all of the limitations that you mention in your example.  I.e. it is reusable, it does not require manually tracking which input is being edited, it works with UITextView's, etc.

Answer (score 18):

Greg's approach should work but I have an approach that doesn't require the keyboard to be told about the text field or text view. In fact, you can create a single instance of the keyboard and assign it to multiple text fields and/or text views. The keyboard handles knowing which one is the first responder.

Here is my approach. I'm not going to show any code for creating the keyboard layout. That's the easy part. This code shows all of the plumbing.

Edit: This has been updated to properly handle `UITextFieldDelegate textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` and `UITextViewDelegate textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:`.

The header file:

```
@interface SomeKeyboard : UIView <UIInputViewAudioFeedback>

@end
```

The implementation file:

```
@implmentation SomeKeyboard {
    id<UITextInput> _input;
    BOOL _tfShouldChange;
    BOOL _tvShouldChange;
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkInput:) name:UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification object:nil];
    }

    return self;
}

// This is used to obtain the current text field/view that is now the first responder
- (void)checkInput:(NSNotification *)notification {
    UITextField *field = notification.object;

    if (field.inputView && self == field.inputView) {
        _input = field;

        _tvShouldChange = NO;
        _tfShouldChange = NO;
        if ([_input isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            id<UITextFieldDelegate> del = [(UITextField *)_input delegate];
            if ([del respondsToSelector:@selector(textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:)]) {
                _tfShouldChange = YES;
            }
        } else if ([_input isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]) {
            id<UITextViewDelegate> del = [(UITextView *)_input delegate];
            if ([del respondsToSelector:@selector(textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:)]) {
                _tvShouldChange = YES;
            }
        }
    }
}

// Call this for each button press
- (void)click {
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] playInputClick];
}

// Call this when a button on the keyboard is tapped (other than return or backspace)
- (void)keyTapped:(UIButton *)button {
    NSString *text = ???; // determine text for the button that was tapped

    if ([_input respondsToSelector:@selector(shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:)]) {
        if ([_input shouldChangeTextInRange:[_input selectedTextRange] replacementText:text]) {
            [_input insertText:text];
        }
    } else if (_tfShouldChange) {
        NSRange range = [(UITextField *)_input selectedRange];
        if ([[(UITextField *)_input delegate] textField:(UITextField *)_input shouldChangeCharactersInRange:range replacementString:text]) {
            [_input insertText:text];
        }
    } else if (_tvShouldChange) {
        NSRange range = [(UITextView *)_input selectedRange];
        if ([[(UITextView *)_input delegate] textView:(UITextView *)_input shouldChangeTextInRange:range replacementText:text]) {
            [_input insertText:text];
        }
    } else {
        [_input insertText:text];
    }
}

// Used for a UITextField to handle the return key button
- (void)returnTapped:(UIButton *)button {
    if ([_input isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        id<UITextFieldDelegate> del = [(UITextField *)_input delegate];
        if ([del respondsToSelector:@selector(textFieldShouldReturn:)]) {
            [del textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)_input];
        }
    } else if ([_input isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]) {
        [_input insertText:@"\n"];
    }
}

// Call this to dismiss the keyboard
- (void)dismissTapped:(UIButton *)button {
    [(UIResponder *)_input resignFirstResponder];
}

// Call this for a delete/backspace key
- (void)backspaceTapped:(UIButton *)button {
    if ([_input respondsToSelector:@selector(shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:)]) {
        UITextRange *range = [_input selectedTextRange];
        if ([range.start isEqual:range.end]) {
            UITextPosition *newStart = [_input positionFromPosition:range.start inDirection:UITextLayoutDirectionLeft offset:1];
            range = [_input textRangeFromPosition:newStart toPosition:range.end];
        }
        if ([_input shouldChangeTextInRange:range replacementText:@""]) {
            [_input deleteBackward];
        }
    } else if (_tfShouldChange) {
        NSRange range = [(UITextField *)_input selectedRange];
        if (range.length == 0) {
            if (range.location > 0) {
                range.location--;
                range.length = 1;
            }
        }
        if ([[(UITextField *)_input delegate] textField:(UITextField *)_input shouldChangeCharactersInRange:range replacementString:@""]) {
            [_input deleteBackward];
        }
    } else if (_tvShouldChange) {
        NSRange range = [(UITextView *)_input selectedRange];
        if (range.length == 0) {
            if (range.location > 0) {
                range.location--;
                range.length = 1;
            }
        }
        if ([[(UITextView *)_input delegate] textView:(UITextView *)_input shouldChangeTextInRange:range replacementText:@""]) {
            [_input deleteBackward];
        }
    } else {
        [_input deleteBackward];
    }

    [self updateShift];
}

@end
```

This class requires a category method for UITextField:

```
@interface UITextField (CustomKeyboard)

- (NSRange)selectedRange;

@end

@implementation UITextField (CustomKeyboard)

- (NSRange)selectedRange {
    UITextRange *tr = [self selectedTextRange];

    NSInteger spos = [self offsetFromPosition:self.beginningOfDocument toPosition:tr.start];
    NSInteger epos = [self offsetFromPosition:self.beginningOfDocument toPosition:tr.end];

    return NSMakeRange(spos, epos - spos);
}

@end
```

Comment: I know this an old answer but I'm trying out your answer and noticed it's giving me an error on [self updateShift]; Is this a method that is supposed to be included in your sample or is it from somewhere else?

Comment: You can take that method call out. In my real custom keyboard, I have a shift key that I update like the shift key on the standard Default keyboard. That's beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: thanks for your help. Do I have to do anything beyond setting my keyboard as the inputView of a textfield? Right now I have it all set up and have tested that it goes into the keyTapped method when a button is pressed, but the textfield is not changing

Comment: Make sure the `checkInput` method is being called when the text field gets focus.

Comment: Take a look at my example to see how to do it without needing to subclass UITextField.

Comment: @lnafziger My approach doesn't require a subclass of `UITextField` either. I added category method just to make getting the selected range easier. And why bring this up 2.5 years later?

Comment: Oops, sorry, category.  And someone else commented which brought this question to my attention and I figured that I would point out another way to do it for you just in case you were curious.  :)

Answer (score 14):

I have created a full working example of a keyboard for the iPad, available on Github here:

https://github.com/lnafziger/Numberpad

> Numberpad is a custom numeric keyboard for the iPad which works with
>   both `UITextField`'s and `UITextView`'s requiring no changes other than
>   adding an instance of the Numberpad class as the inputView of the text
>   field/view.

Features:

- It is covered under the MIT licence, so may be freely copied and used per its' terms.
- It works with UITextFields and UITextViews
- It does not require a delegate to be set.
- It automatically keeps track of which view is the first responder (so you don't have to)
- You do not have to set the size of the keyboard, or keep track of it.
- There is a shared instance that you can use for as many input views as you like, without using extra memory for each one.

Usage is as simple as including Numberpad.h and then:

```
theTextField.inputView  = [Numberpad defaultNumberpad];
```

Everything else is taken care of automatically!

Either grab the two class files and the xib from Github (link above), or create the buttons (in code or in a storyboard/xib) with their actions set to the appropriate methods in the class (numberpadNumberPressed, numberpadDeletePressed, numberpadClearPressed, or numberpadDonePressed).

**The following code is out of date.  See the Github project for the latest code.**

Numberpad.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Numberpad : UIViewController

// The one and only Numberpad instance you should ever need:
+ (Numberpad *)defaultNumberpad;

@end
```

Numberpad.m:

```
#import "Numberpad.h"

#pragma mark - Private methods

@interface Numberpad ()

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<UITextInput> targetTextInput;

@end

#pragma mark - Numberpad Implementation

@implementation Numberpad

@synthesize targetTextInput;

#pragma mark - Shared Numberpad method

+ (Numberpad *)defaultNumberpad {
    static Numberpad *defaultNumberpad = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        defaultNumberpad = [[Numberpad alloc] init];
    });

    return defaultNumberpad;
}

#pragma mark - view lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Keep track of the textView/Field that we are editing
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(editingDidBegin:)
                                                 name:UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification
                                               object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(editingDidBegin:)
                                                 name:UITextViewTextDidBeginEditingNotification
                                               object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(editingDidEnd:)
                                                 name:UITextFieldTextDidEndEditingNotification
                                               object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(editingDidEnd:)
                                                 name:UITextViewTextDidEndEditingNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification
                                                  object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:UITextViewTextDidBeginEditingNotification
                                                  object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:UITextFieldTextDidEndEditingNotification
                                                  object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:UITextViewTextDidEndEditingNotification
                                                  object:nil];
    self.targetTextInput = nil;

    [super viewDidUnload];
}

#pragma mark - editingDidBegin/End

// Editing just began, store a reference to the object that just became the firstResponder
- (void)editingDidBegin:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if (![notification.object conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInput)]) {
        self.targetTextInput = nil;
        return;
    }

    self.targetTextInput = notification.object;
}

// Editing just ended.
- (void)editingDidEnd:(NSNotification *)notification {
    self.targetTextInput = nil;
}

#pragma mark - Keypad IBActions

// A number (0-9) was just pressed on the number pad
// Note that this would work just as well with letters or any other character and is not limited to numbers.
- (IBAction)numberpadNumberPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    if (!self.targetTextInput) {
        return;
    }

    NSString *numberPressed  = sender.titleLabel.text;
    if ([numberPressed length] == 0) {
        return;
    }

    UITextRange *selectedTextRange = self.targetTextInput.selectedTextRange;
    if (!selectedTextRange) {
        return;
    }

    [self textInput:self.targetTextInput replaceTextAtTextRange:selectedTextRange withString:numberPressed];
}

// The delete button was just pressed on the number pad
- (IBAction)numberpadDeletePressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    if (!self.targetTextInput) {
        return;
    }

    UITextRange *selectedTextRange = self.targetTextInput.selectedTextRange;
    if (!selectedTextRange) {
        return;
    }

    // Calculate the selected text to delete
    UITextPosition  *startPosition  = [self.targetTextInput positionFromPosition:selectedTextRange.start offset:-1];
    if (!startPosition) {
        return;
    }
    UITextPosition  *endPosition    = selectedTextRange.end;
    if (!endPosition) {
        return;
    }
    UITextRange     *rangeToDelete  = [self.targetTextInput textRangeFromPosition:startPosition
                                                                       toPosition:endPosition];

    [self textInput:self.targetTextInput replaceTextAtTextRange:rangeToDelete withString:@""];
}

// The clear button was just pressed on the number pad
- (IBAction)numberpadClearPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    if (!self.targetTextInput) {
        return;
    }

    UITextRange *allTextRange = [self.targetTextInput textRangeFromPosition:self.targetTextInput.beginningOfDocument
                                                                 toPosition:self.targetTextInput.endOfDocument];

    [self textInput:self.targetTextInput replaceTextAtTextRange:allTextRange withString:@""];
}

// The done button was just pressed on the number pad
- (IBAction)numberpadDonePressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    if (!self.targetTextInput) {
        return;
    }

    // Call the delegate methods and resign the first responder if appropriate
    if ([self.targetTextInput isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]) {
        UITextView *textView = (UITextView *)self.targetTextInput;
        if ([textView.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(textViewShouldEndEditing:)]) {
            if ([textView.delegate textViewShouldEndEditing:textView]) {
                [textView resignFirstResponder];
            }
        }
    } else if ([self.targetTextInput isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)self.targetTextInput;
        if ([textField.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(textFieldShouldEndEditing:)]) {
            if ([textField.delegate textFieldShouldEndEditing:textField]) {
                [textField resignFirstResponder];
            }
        }
    }
}

#pragma mark - text replacement routines

// Check delegate methods to see if we should change the characters in range
- (BOOL)textInput:(id <UITextInput>)textInput shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range withString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (!textInput) {
        return NO;
    }

    if ([textInput isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)textInput;
        if ([textField.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:)]) {
            if (![textField.delegate textField:textField
                 shouldChangeCharactersInRange:range
                             replacementString:string]) {
                return NO;
            }
        }
    } else if ([textInput isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]) {
        UITextView *textView = (UITextView *)textInput;
        if ([textView.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:)]) {
            if (![textView.delegate textView:textView
                     shouldChangeTextInRange:range
                             replacementText:string]) {
                return NO;
            }
        }
    }
    return YES;
}

// Replace the text of the textInput in textRange with string if the delegate approves
- (void)textInput:(id <UITextInput>)textInput replaceTextAtTextRange:(UITextRange *)textRange withString:(NSString *)string {
    if (!textInput) {
        return;
    }
    if (!textRange) {
        return;
    }

    // Calculate the NSRange for the textInput text in the UITextRange textRange:
    int startPos                    = [textInput offsetFromPosition:textInput.beginningOfDocument
                                                         toPosition:textRange.start];
    int length                      = [textInput offsetFromPosition:textRange.start
                                                         toPosition:textRange.end];
    NSRange selectedRange           = NSMakeRange(startPos, length);

    if ([self textInput:textInput shouldChangeCharactersInRange:selectedRange withString:string]) {
        // Make the replacement:
        [textInput replaceRange:textRange withText:string];
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

(This is mostly taken from http://blog.carbonfive.com/2012/03/12/customizing-the-ios-keyboard/)

In iOS, the keyboard for a view is managed by the `UIResponder` part of the view inheritance chain. When any UIResponder that needs a keyboard becomes the first responder (is taped or otherwise activated), the UIResponder looks in its `inputView` property for the view to display as the keyboard. So, to make a custom keyboard and respond to event on it, you have to create a view with letter buttons, associate a view controller with that view, and with the buttons to handle the presses, and you have to set that view as the `inputView` of some textbox.

Take a look at the link for more information.