# iPhone: Custom keyboard layout and theme

Tags: ios, xcode, keyboard, themes, customization

I am wondering if anyone knows how to or can like me to some documentation or tutorials on how to make custom iOS keyboard sets as well as theming the iOS keyboard. I have read everything I could find, watched many youtube videos and read related posts on here. Most are just making a keyboard from scratch with a bunch of buttons or just tell you how to use the other iOS layouts like email, keypad etc. I need to create a custom keypad set. It must be able to be done, the Wolfram|Alpha Calculus apps have custom keyboard layouts and modified themes. If anyone has any info, please send it my way!

Example from the wolfram app:

[image: Wolfram App Example]

Comment: What more info do you want? The keyboard in the image you posted is a custom keyboard made up of a bunch of buttons. There is no other way to create a custom keyboard. What do you mean by "custom keypad set"?

Comment: Like cant you define a custom set for the default iOS keyboard? Like how there is the email set, keypad set, url set, etc. Can you not create a custom set?

Comment: No. You create a custom UIView that represents the keyboard you want. Then you assign this view to the `inputView` property of a `UITextField` or `UITextView`. You can't define a new keyboard type if that's what you mean by "custom set". There is no way at all to modify any of the existing keyboards either (other than adding an `inputAccessoryView` to the top of a keyboard).

Comment: Well thats disappointing. Well time to try and figure something out. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know why this is disappointing. If you create your custom keyboard correctly, you can reuse it for any number of text fields. Instead of setting the `keyboardType` you set the `inputView`. See [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13205160/how-do-i-retrieve-keystrokes-from-a-custom-keyboard-on-an-ios-app/13205494#13205494) for a useful framework for a reusable keyboard. Just add the buttons.