# UITextField keyboardType in iPad and iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, uikeyboardtype

The keyboard type:`UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad` in iPad is different in iPhone, i just want to use the iPhone type in iPad no idea how to make it.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597619/uikeyboardtypenumberpad-show-just-numbes-on-ipad

Answer (score 2):

There is no separate numeric keyboard for iPad. If you set it on the iPad, the keyboard will just show up and it will be se to to the "numbers and symbols" mode. If you want a numeric keyboard similar to the one on the iPhone, you should create a custom keyboard for the iPad.

Comment: Thanks, I just see the keyboard in iOS. Settings->General->Restrictions->Enable... So, I think if there is a way to implement it , a custom keyboard is unnecessary.